# Why is lube for foreplay/sex permitted?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, sex, husband-wife

Sex toys are not allowed because you are using a foreign object to pleasure yourself when only any part of the spouse's body can be used. In the same way lubrication such as KY Jelly is not natural but external to the human. Why don't the scholars argue that your natural lubrication from both of your privates is enough. Otherwise this is inconsistent with the sex toy ruling is it not?

Comment: AFAIK the use of Condoms is also permitted which also goes against the logic used for foreign objects, I think this just shows the flaws in the logic used to base such prohibitions on. I don't believe there is strong enough evidence for such prohibitions.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. I wonder if this post is on-topic. And this also lacks information you should show us or give us references for the claims made.

Answer (score 2):

Without confirming or denying the legality of this, the point on lube doesn't seem to be an equal comparison.

**Necessity:** Allah (ﷻ) designed male anatomy to penetrate females and provide pleasure. So the tools/toys are not even needed when men have their hands, mouths and privates [many different ways to sufficiently please the spouse]. On the other hand, medically speaking- not all women produce enough natural wetness to have comfortable sex and may be in pain otherwise. Cases like this would warrant the use of pure lubricants.

**Competition/Substitution:** Although both are foreign objects, the toys "compete" with male privates (and often are used for pleasure as a substitute by people who engage in homosexuality/lesbianism/masturbation -it's mostly used for evil) whereas the lubricant is an "aid" for the natural anatomy and by itself provides no pleasure [same story with condoms].

Comment: +1 for your content in "Competition/Substitution"

Comment: simply, toys are substitution to the other, lube r an aid. salute